# How to implement external close request like process.CloseMainWindow

Tags: c#, winforms

I like my windows forms application to close based on a close request from another application using process.CloseMainWindow().

I could not find any way to pickup / receive the external close request in the main form.

Comment: `process.CloseMainWindow()` sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to the process' foreground window, if any. To handle `WM_CLOSE` you'll need to override `Form.WndProc` and check for `WM_CLOSE` and call `.Close()` and/or `Application.Exit()` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation in the main form can be done like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    
    if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE)
    {
        // Close everything
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```